# SplitView or a CustomView in iOS

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, custom-view

I am working on an app that really needs to use several tables and various views. I initially thought that I should use a splitview controller. However, I don't like the amount of space the masterview takes up and the limitations imposed by the split view. So I'm considering using a custom view that has a sub view containing a table. I know this is possible, but is it acceptable?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by acceptable? What suggestions are you looking for?

Comment: Just if it is considered acceptable or good practice to add a UITable as a subview of a view as opposed to the table occupying it's own view? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I might get it - is your concern having a single view controller responsible for a table view, and your various detail views? Or am I missing the point? Just about any view you'd create would have a super view and it's not clear what 'occupying its own view' means unless that's a reference to a view controller solely responsible for a table view.

Comment: I suppose that's the issue I'm having. Typically, when you see a tableview in an iOS app it is in it's own view. What I did was to add a subview on the main view of the view controller. This subview was then loaded with a tableview. Obviously there are other views on the page i.e. labels, buttons etc. Right now I guess it kind of looks a bit odd.

Thanks for your comments and assistance.

Comment: You could make your own split-view-like controller by adding two container views (in IB) to a controller's view. You can size them however you like. Delete the vc that you get automatically with the container view, and add a table view controller instead.

Comment: Thanks, rdelmar. I actually played with that today. I like it, but things get confusing with multiple interfaces. I have been thinking of a full screen interface with the different views in a tab bar controller. In a couple of these I have need a table view. Thus my dilemma: most tables are presented in their own view. Here, I'm considering inserting the table as a subview of the viewcontroller. I just haven't seen this often.